# how msbuild finds the starting target. is there any new convention?

Tags: .net, msbuild, csproj

I just noticed that there is not any `<import>` in the .csproj files anymore.
Where is the starting target?
How does it find `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets`
Is there any document to explain the new msbuild ?
Here is an example:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: The Project's `Sdk` attribute gets the ball rolling.  Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets has an `Import` to import Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short the project SDKs do automatic includes. Those includes almost certainly have a default target set in  them.

> .NET Core and .NET 5 and later projects are associated with a software development kit (SDK). Each project SDK is a set of MSBuild targets and associated tasks that are responsible for compiling, packing, and publishing code. A project that references a project SDK is sometimes referred to as an SDK-style project.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview

You can also probably use the --preprocess command line option or /bl and msbuild log viewer so get an idea of what the file looks like after imports are handled.